# What is the right way to add onClick event on element after render?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to add onClick event only on an element of the list(array)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      list: ['Value1','Value2']
    }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.list.map(data => {
          return data
        })} // How can I add onClick event only on 'Value1' after it rendered?
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My solution is:

```
const [Value1,Value2] = this.state.list
value1.addEventListener('click',function(){})
```

but it seems like doesn't work.

Comment: why after rendering?

Comment: An app is already built like that. It requires me to add onClick event to an element in the array list.

Comment: Instead of adding the onClick event after render, it is possible to define it from the beginning, and decide in it how to handle the event, based on a state variable that indicates if a render already happened and on the clicked array item's value.

Comment: as @Yossi and Mayank said, you don't need to add onClick after rendering.

Comment: Yes it is possible to define it from the state. How can I do that @Yossi ?

Comment: I see that somebody answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `React`, you can bind `onClick` in the component. You can read more about event handling in here: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Your code can be changed into this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      list: ['Value1', 'Value2']
    }
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    console.log('You clicked the item!!')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.list.map(data => {
          return (
            <span onClick={data === 'Value1' ? this.handleClick : undefined}>
              {data}
            </span>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to add onClick on only 1 element list[0] which is 'Value1' not the whole list

Comment: Sorry. I read the problem too quick. I update my answer to match what you want.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my question. I am just curious if we do @Yossi way above "define it from the beginning, and decide in it how to handle the event, based on a state variable that indicates if a render already happened and on the clicked array item's value". How can we do it?

Comment: I think I understand what he wants to say, but I don't totally agree with that solution. I think he says you can use a state to define which item is clicked. And if the `Value1` item is clicked, you handle addition actions. There is the problem about this solution, is that you can `if...else...` directly in `handleClick` by passing `data` to the function. It also makes your `handleClick` func doing more than one works, which is bad for maintaining the code (in some advance programming which I'm still learning). But maybe I understand him wrong.